# Unable to run PHP Script on WAMP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to Wampp server; I installed it and tried writing a php program:

```
<?php
$db_name="webappdb";
$mysql_user="root";
$mysql_pass="root";
$server_name="localhost:81";

$con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);
if(!$con)
{
    echo"Connection Error...".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
    echo"<h3>Database connection Success....</h3>";
}
?>
```

When I run the code I get this error:

[image: error screenshot]

Can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Comment: use `$server_name="localhost";`

Comment: are you using a port?

Answer (score 0):

Check the port your MySQL-Server is running. Default port ist `3306` not `81`. This looks like a mis-configuration.

Furthermore set `$server_name="localhost"` and remove the port.

Answer (score 0):

The MYSQL Server runs on port 3306 and is configured as such in the php.ini

If you have changed Apache to run on port 81, which is I assume why you added 81 to the below variable, then that has nothing to do with the port that the MYSQL Server is running on

Change this line

```
$server_name="localhost:81";
```

To

```
$server_name="localhost";
```

Or possibly for a little extra speed

```
$server_name="127.0.0.1";
```